# how to provide different result view for new user

Tags: bixby

How do I provide a different result-view message or layout for a new user?

In this case, I want the view to be different depending on whether the user is a new user as shown in the UserData concept, whose values I compute in the action GetAltBrainsData. 
I have given UserData the feature profile-stored.

```
result-view {
  match: AltBrainsData (this) 
  { 
  from-output: GetAltBrainsData (getaltbrainsdata)
  }

  message {

    //here is where i want to check if UserData.newuser = true and vary the answer
  //if (userdata.newuser) {template("hello new user")} else ...


    if (size(this) > 1) {
    template ("I found #{(size(this))} AltBrains")
    }
    else-if (size(this) == 1 ) {
    template ("") {speech ("#{value(this.name)}")}
    }
    else {template ("No AltBrains matched the search.")}
     }

  render {

    // if UserData.newuser = true then welcome layout
```

but the result-view still doesn't seem to be aware of UserData.The IDE complains that it is an illegal expression in userdata.newuser

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (getaltbrainsdata.userdata.newuser)`, or whatever you had named the `UserData` as in your action's model.

Another way to approach this is to access it with a match pattern like

```
result-view {
  match: AltBrainsData (this) 
  { 
  from-output: GetAltBrainsData (getaltbrainsdata) {
      from-input: UserData (userData)
  }
...
```

Comment: Helpful as always. Using match pattern, basically developer can reference any concept "grouped together by action" in views.